# Как добавить toolbar в PreferenceActivity?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-preferences

Как добавить toolbar в PreferenceActivity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это работает.

settings_toolbar.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/settings_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:titleTextColor="@color/textColor" />
```

OnCreate

```
getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.settings_toolbar, (ViewGroup)findViewById(android.R.id.content));
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.settings_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Отступы от тулбара

```
int horizontalMargin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 2, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
int verticalMargin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 2, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
int topMargin = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.activity_vertical_margin) + 30, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
getListView().setPadding(horizontalMargin, topMargin, horizontalMargin, verticalMargin);
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так: создайте `xml` в `layout` папке:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/settings_toolbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"
    app:title="Settings" />
```

Затем подключите его в разметке настроек:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/settings_toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" />
```

И в методе `onCreate` инициализируйте

```
private void initToolbar() {
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.settings_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);        

    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(R.string.activity_title_settings);
}
```

Comment: Я прописывал, почему то это не работает.

Comment: @Colibri обновил ответ

Comment: `getSupportActionBar();` возвращает `null`

Comment: а если setSupportActionBar();?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я нешел рабочий вариант.